# Collapsible in footer does not expand to full width

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, footer, cordova-3

I have upgraded my Phonegap/Cordova App to the latest Cordova, jQuery and jQuery Mobile versions. Now I am unable to have a collapsible div with full width. The below code gives me a full width in content part but in footer it only displays a limited width (used to work earlier):

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
   <h3>I'm a header</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content.</p>
</div>
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from Inspecting the collapsible element in the footer is treated as a button and gets the `display: inline-block` css setting which makes it button size. Changing this to block enables full width.

[image]

**CSS**

```
.ui-footer .ui-btn {
display: block !important;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/azhqam98/

Comment: Any idea how Expand/Collapse will work dynamically in this case. I have tried $('#hideshow').trigger('expand'); but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Anjum its,  $( ".selector" ).collapsible( "expand" );  --- and (collapse)

Comment: Thanks @Tasos. It was working with previous version of JQ, but now it doesn't. Your hint was very helpful. Regards.

Comment: @Anjum yeah i always assume the recent 1.4+ versions as (trigger) is now depreciated in JQM

Comment: You mean my statements like $('.htmlSelector').trigger('create');$('.htmlSelector').trigger('refresh');$( "#Panelselector" ).trigger( "updatelayout" ); won't work? Can u please send me to a quick page which could guide me about the replacements?

Comment: @Anjum -- this is the most recent page for options, methods, and events for collapsible widgets --- http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/

Comment: I was asking about trigger's replacements, not collapsible

Comment: @Anjum - what JQM version are you using?? if 1.4+ then trigger has depreciated in all widgets. check the list here for new methods -- http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/widgets/

Comment: Thanks @Tasos. Yes I have upgraded to the latest versions of JQM as well as Cordova and my whole App is broken :-( I actually moved up as some users were complaining that their ListView is freezing and they are unable to scroll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68170/discussion-between-tasos-and-anjum).